# Spacewalk 2.10 CentOS 8 pacakge name with module_el8 name

Tags: centos, spacewalk

In my Spacewalk system I have configured CentOS 8 based and AppSteam repo with latest packages and added channel to my CentOS 8 server. it shows `module_el8.1.0+229+cd132df8.noarch` available to install. but this package name is different from what is installed on the servers. I like to understand what is this package with `module_el8`, How can I exclude this from my spacewalk repo.

if I push the package from Spacewalk I get this message

```
Client execution returned "Failed: Packages failed to install properly: Package perl-constant-0:1.33-1001.module_el8.1.0+229+cd132df8.noarch is not available for installation Package perl-Digest-MD5-0:2.55-397.module_el8.1.0+229+cd132df8.x86_64 is not available for installation Package perl-Exporter-0:5.72-1001.module_el8.1.0+229+cd132df8.noarch is not available for installation Package perl-File-Temp-0:0.230.600-2.module_el8.1.0+229+cd132df8.noarch is not available for installation Package perl-IO-Socket-IP-0:0.39-6.module_el8.1.0+229+cd132df8.noarch is not available for installation Package perl-libnet-0:3.11-4.module_el8.1.0+229+cd132df8.noarch is not available for installation Package perl-MIME-Base64-0:3.15-1001.module_el8.1.0+229+cd132df8.x86_64 is not available for installation Package perl-parent-1:0.237-2.module_el8.1.0+229+cd132df8.noarch is not available for installation Package perl-Pod-Escapes-1:1.07-396.module_el8.1.0+229+cd132df8.noarch is not available for installation Package perl-Pod-Perldoc-0:3.28-397.module_el8.1.0+" (code 32)
```

[image]

[image]
    Thanks

Comment: Interesting similarity with https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/584963/117549

Comment: You should probably stop using Spacewalk and migrate to other choice.  The Spacewalk will be discontinued 31 May, 2020 (https://spacewalkproject.github.io).

Comment: your correct, but this issue is CentOS 8 repo issue, trying to figure out the fix.

Comment: Yes, it is.  See my answer, just wanted you to know it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the name contains a `+` character.  The Cloudfront (with dedicated S3 bucket) does not process correctly files with `+`.

Try a fallback mirror outside *EC2/AWS*, if you do `yum clean all`.  Then it should work correctly.